# Ошибка в цикле - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

Вот мой код на Пайтоне, не знаю что делать, не могу найти ошибку.

> IndexError: list index out of range

Что означает данная проблема и как ее разрешить, я не знаю. 
Буду благодарен каждому кто даст ответ, уже нет сил на это.

```
f = open("27_A.txt")
spis = []
s = 0
min = 99999999999
for l in f:
    a = list(map(int, l.split()))
    a.sort()
    for j in range(2):
        if (a[2] - a[j]) % 109 != 0 and a[2] - a[j] < min:
            min = a[2] - a[j]
    s += a[2]
if s % 109 != 0:
    print(s)
else:
    print(s-min)
```

Comment: выход индекса за пределы списка

Comment: А сколько у вас элементов в `a`? Если иногда попадается меньше чем 3, то `a[2]` будет вылетать с такой ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

> IndexError: list index out of range

Ты вышел за пределы списка, указав неправильный индекс. К примеру:

```
spisok = [1,2,3,4,5] // В списке 5 элементов, максимальный индекс 4
n = spisok[5] // Пробуем присвоить переменной несуществующий элемент с индексом 5
```

И как итог, получаем соответствующую ошибку.